# Error when downloading Pyterrier on VsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently wanting to download [`Pyterrier`](https://pyterrier.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for a project i'm working on I have spent hours trying to fix this issue and have no clue how to resolve it.

Here is what the error that keeps coming up is, I have downloaded java but don't know what seems to the be issue or how to resolve it.

[image: screenshot of the error]

If anyone has advice please let me know I would be very greatful.

Comment: maybe reading the error message will help you

Answer (score 0):

> unable to determine jdk_home

Please check whether **Java_JDK** and **JRE** is installed.

You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076881/18359438) and try to run the command as **administrator**.